# Editing an existing PDF without using iText

Tags: java, pdf

I want to add an index page to existing PDF file. And add page numbers to the page of the pdf file.
All the suggested solutions point towards creating a new pdf and merging the existing pdf file with the new one.

Is there any other way for this ??
Also I dont want to use itext since its not free for commercial uses.

Comment: There are other PDF libraries around, too, some commercial, some free to a certain degree. As you don't seem to want to spend money for a PDF library, PDFBox might be something for you. Alternatively iText up to version 4.2 might be something for you to look at if you don't need to be state-of-the-art; new versions are AGPL or commercial.

Comment: Problem with PDFBox is it doesnt supports editing existing pdf. You need to create a new pdf file every time you want to add a page to the existing pdf file.

Comment: If by *editing existing pdf* you mean that you have to save the result of the manipulation with a different file name... so what? Otherwise please explain.

Comment: I per my understanding for adding a new page & content, you need to create a new pdf add new content and then merge the existing pdf. I wanted to avoid the merging step. Renaming is not the issue.

Comment: @mkl The Java version was LGPL or MPL up to inclusive 2.1.7.

Comment: @his actually even up to the consolidating 4.2 release.

Comment: @mkl The last iText _release_ for Java under LGLP/MPL was 2.1.7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321207/what-is-latest-version-of-itext-that-is-not-agpl . 4.2 for was never released for Java. Anyhow, even the leak is years old and it is worth paying the price for 5. I only wish they were more transparent with the pricing.

Comment: @his 4.2 was not *released to the wild* according to the answer you refer to. According to the SVN commit comments (revisions 4106 and 4107) by Bruno, though, *Unofficial release: iText 4.2.0* [...] *is the final version of iText available as an MPL/LGPL library. This release is not jarred, nor officially released on the iText web site. If you need it, you'll have to compile your own jar files.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments to the original question, you think in PDFBox

> for adding a new page & content, you need to create a new pdf add new content and then merge the existing pdf. I wanted to avoid the merging step. Renaming is not the issue

You might want to try something like this:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new FileInputStream(new File("original.pdf")));
PDPage page = new PDPage();
// fill page
doc.addPage(page);
doc.save("original-plus-page.pdf");
```

**EDIT:** In a comment to the answer the question arose how to *insert a new page at specific index(page number).* To do this, obviously the `doc.addPage(page)` has to be changed somehow.

Originally this `PDDocument` method is defined like this:

```
/**
 * This will add a page to the document.  This is a convenience method, that
 * will add the page to the root of the hierarchy and set the parent of the
 * page to the root.
 *
 * @param page The page to add to the document.
 */
public void addPage( PDPage page )
{
    PDPageNode rootPages = getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
    rootPages.getKids().add( page );
    page.setParent( rootPages );
    rootPages.updateCount();
}
```

We merely need a similar function which merely does not simply `add` the page to the kids but instead adds it at a given index. Thus a helper method like the following in our code will do:

```
public static void addPage(PDDocument doc, int index, PDPage page)
{
    PDPageNode rootPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
    rootPages.getKids().add(index, page);
    page.setParent(rootPages);
    rootPages.updateCount();
}
```

If you now replace the line

```
doc.addPage(page);
```

in the code of the original answer by

```
addPage(doc, page, 0);
```

the empty page is added up front.

Comment: Btw does PDFbox or anyother free & opensource library supports creating internal links in a pdf document ?